# ASP.Net MVC foreach loop not persisting changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have what I think is a simple situation - but I've been stuck on it for a while now.

I am simply querying the database, and putting the results into a viewmodel: `CallVM` - that part works fine.

What I then want to do, it loop through the `QueueByTeam` object, and update one of the properties - however, the "looping" part, doesn't save the changes to the `QueueByTeam` object, so when I return the object to the View, my updates have been ignored:

```
  var QueueByTeam = db.Calls.Where(x => x.assignedteam == id)
         .Select(call => new CallVM
          {
              customer = call.customer,
              nexttargetdate = call.nexttargetdate
              owner = "";
          });


        foreach (var calls in QueueByTeam)
        {
            calls.owner = "--------";
        }
        // at this point, QueueByTeam has ignored changing the `owner` field to "-------"           
        return View(QueueByTeam.ToList());
```

Do I need to do something after the foreach loop to save the changes, before returning to the View?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: What happens if you put the `ToList()` statement on the end of the select statement.  This would force the read of the database and store it locally?

Comment: Could you not put `calls.owner = "-----" in place of `owner = ""`?

Comment: @bob-vale - thank you, that's exactly what the problem was.  Can you make that an answer, and I'll mark it as such.  Thanks too shahkalpesh for helping.  Mark

Comment: Just to clarify, the main point is `call => new CallVM`. Your query creates new unattached objects and the query is executed 2x.

Answer (score 2):

Change the code to:

```
 var QueueByTeam = db.Calls.Where(x => x.assignedteam == id)
     .Select(call => new CallVM
      {
          customer = call.customer,
          nexttargetdate = call.nexttargetdate
          owner = "";
      })
      .ToList();


    foreach (var calls in QueueByTeam)
    {
        calls.owner = "--------";
    }
    // at this point, QueueByTeam has ignored changing the `owner` field to "-------"           
    return View(QueueByTeam);
```

i.e. Put the `ToList()` straight after the `Select`, before you try and change the data.  This forces the database query to run immediately and stores the result in a list.

From the looks of it every time you queried your `QueuesByTeam` it was requerying the database hence losing your changes.

As a side note, if the change is just to set the owner to `"-----"` you could put that straight into the original select statement instead of having a seperate for loop.